# Postgres equivalent to MS-SQL SELECT DataSet needed (returning multiple tables in one query)

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I'm looking for a possibility to retrieve multiple DataTables (within one DataSet), using npgsql and a postgres function (stored procedure). Though my postgres function in general works already, I don't get back 2 separate tables, but only one table, containing all results of all queries (both when executing the function via pgAdmin and via npgsql / NpgsqlDataAdapter.Fill).

See my simplified sample here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "MyFunction"(_parameter character varying)
RETURNS SETOF "MyView" AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
return query SELECT * FROM "MyView" WHERE "Col1" = 'A' AND "Col2" = _parameter;
return query SELECT * FROM "MyView" WHERE "Col1" = 'B' AND "Col2" = _parameter;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100
ROWS 1000;
```

Using caller:

```
SELECT * FROM "MyFunction"('abc');
```

Isn't there ANY way to get returned a DataSet containing SEPARATE DataTables using npgsql.dll? The query must not necessarily be via a postgres function - if it wpuld be possible to get such DataSet with separate tables by simply using ngpsql ExecuteScalar that would even be preferable... Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Hmm. I know the code that returns multiple resultsets for `NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()` fairly well (I did a rewrite on it a few years back) and `NpgsqlDataAdapter.Fill()` should call into that, but that code I don't know well. It could be that `NpgsqlDataAdapter.Fill()` handles `NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()` incorrectly, and that this is a bug.

Comment: @FranciscoJunior would be the person who'd know.

Comment: Thanks Jon Hanna,I made my function working by using NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(). When comparing this solution with the SqlDataAdapter.Fill() method, this approach requires quite some more work and many of lines of code - however, it's working  :-)

Answer (score 0):

It should not work - PostgreSQL doesn't support multirecord set. With one trick you can returns set of returned cursors.

RETURN QUERY send result to output, but there are no clean border between results of two RETURN QUERY usage. It is same as UNION.

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT 1;
RETURN QUERY SELECT 1;
RETURN;
```

is same as:

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2;
RETURN;
```